# google-app-engine full-text-search ,which is better , "google custom search" or whoosh

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search, whoosh

this is [whoosh](http://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine)

so ,did you know which is better ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Custom Search Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/docs/start.html#overview) won't search over your models unless they are published fairly completely on a page which Google has crawled and indexed.  Think of CSE as a very configurable search engine over existing Google search results.

Whoosh appears to be a better fit if you want to search over models in your datastore.  Another option for this functionality is Bill Katz's [SearchableModel](http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine).